# Solution of Integral equations (using Fourier Transform)

Tags: fourier-transform, integral-equations

Please help me to solve the Integral equation :

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos sx \mathrm{d}x = e^{-s}$$

using Fourier Transform $s>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

First see that the equation make sense if the left ahnd side is also and even function
that is we have, since the right hand side is an even function too. $$e^{-|s|} =\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos sx \mathrm{d}x = \frac12\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{isx}dx +\frac12\int_0^\infty  f(x)e^{-isx}dx \\ = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-x)e^{-isx}dx +\frac12\int_0^\infty  f(x)e^{-isx}dx  = \color{red}{\int_\Bbb R  \widetilde{f}(x)e^{-isx}dx }$$

where $$ \widetilde{f}(x) =\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$
Using the fourier inverse we get

$$ \widetilde{f}(x) =\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\Bbb R e^{-|s|} e^{isx}ds=.......}$$

Comment: I follow till that . But , what next ?

Comment: @Das see the edit reload your page

Comment: Best I can figure out is , f(x) + f(-x) = the improper Integral . Mind , completing the solution in full , please ??? 

Comment: You’re asking about Fourier transforms and can’t compute that integral? C’mon 

Comment: As I have already pointed out , I am a novice .

Comment: Please help if you can .

Comment: @Das What is the problem with that integral

Comment: I have already solved the Integral . Thanks to all of you